# How to select n columns from a matrix minimizing a given function

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, feature-selection, greedy

I must buy **one of each product**, but I can visit **no more then n shops**. Which n shops should I choose to spend the least amount of money? Products are not divisible, every shop have full inventory.

|  | Shop A | Shop B | Shop C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | $10.00 | $12.00 | $9.99 |
| Product 2 | $8.50 | $9.99 | $7.99 |
| Product 3 | $15.00 | $14.50 | $16.99 |

So I need to  minimize
`df.min(axis=1).sum()` , where df represents any combination of n columns.

The brute force algorithm would be:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,4], 'B': [3,1,3], 'C': [2,3,1]})
best_so_far = df.iloc[:, 0]
n = 2
for combo in  combinations(df.columns, n):
    selection = df[list(combo)].min(axis=1)
    if selection.sum() < best_so_far.sum():
        best_so_far = selection
```

**The goal is to improve time complexity.** Using greedy approach, or dynamic programming doesn't work here, as there is no optimal subproblem. Sorting columns also doesn't help, because a shop (with half of its products prohibitively expensive and the other half almost free) can have a biggest total sum of its products, but still be the best candidate.

Comment: You could formulate this as in integer linear program with binary variables: `Xij = 1` if product `j` is purchased at store `i`, else `= 0`; and `Si = 1` if store i is available, else `= 0`. One would then minimize `Σij CijXij`, where `Cij` is the cost of purchasing product `j` from store `i`, subject to constraints `Xij <= Si` for all `i,j` (can only purchase at store `i` if store `i` is available), `Σi Xij = 1` for all products `j` (each product is purchased at some store), `Σi Si <= n` (at most `n` stores available). Then solve with an ILP software package (commercial or public domain).

Comment: Upfront you could  check if you can eliminate shops which are more expensive for all products that a other shop.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland. I implemented your solution in python and posted below. May you add anything about time complexity of the solution?

Comment: @Async, looks good, but where's the output? The time it takes to solve ILP's can range from milliseconds to years, so nothing can be said about time-complexity.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am interested in time an algorithm takes as the input size grows, expressed using big O notation.

Comment: @Async, there is no big-O for ILP, just as there is no big-O for `π^n`.

Comment: Note that it has been proven that there is no polynomial bound on the number of pivot operations required to solve an ordinary linear program as a function of the number of variables (dimensionality), so that would apply to ILPs as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is why am interested in how ILP (or other possible methods) is implemented under the hood, and what is the complexity of underlying solution. Your answer is really great starting point, but only a starting point.

Comment: If you can come with a big-O for ILP's you will be in line for a [Fields Medal](https://www.britannica.com/science/Fields-Medal).

Comment: It occurred to me that we have been talking about different thing regarding big-O: I have been referring to ILPs generally, you have been referring to your specific problem. I don't see you can do better than `O(m!/(n!*(m-n)!))`, where `m` is the number of shops from which `n` are to be selected.

Comment: @gtomer, could you elaborate on why you voted to close the question and what changes to the question are needed for it to be considered for re-opening? "Debugging" does not seem relevant here.

Comment: @MrSmith42 As the dataset grows, the search for such shop (with all product more expensive) becomes more time-consuming, and the chances of finding it approach zero. So not, but thank you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Assuming the complexity can't be reduced for this specific problem, I will try to use some feature reduction techniques (eliminating some shops with the least chance of being selected) and sacrifice the certainty of finding the best outcome. Any other idea welcomed.

Comment: From your last comment it seems that you need a solution to a real problem you are facing (as opposed to it being an exercise to solve a hypothetical one). If so, why not just use ILP?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My job is to rigorously prove that brute force time complexity can't be improved for this specific case. Generating all permutations of a set of items is O(n!) and it should be multiplied by the number of products so O(p*n!). At this point I need to find a compromise, a heuristic, maybe based on ILP, and sadly I won't be able to share it with you, because now this topic is closed.

Comment: Note that it's combinations of `n` stores selected, not permutations. Once the `n` stores are selected it's of course trivial to determine where each product should be sourced (assuming one is not obliged to buy at least one product from each store). Numbers of combinations is what I gave in my penultimate comment above. (I love to use that word; "antepenultimate" and "preantepenultimate" are even better.) I regret that I can't help with the proof you desire.

Comment: Complexity theory says very little how long a given MIP solver needs for a given MIP problem of a given size with a given data set.

Answer (score 1):

This code solves the problem. Sadly I am not interested in the output itself, but in complexity. How many steps should I do when trying to simulate underlying algorithm on paper?

```
import pulp

# You could formulate this as in integer linear program with binary variables:
problem = pulp.LpProblem("Product Purchase Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Define the decision variables
stores = ["Store 1", "Store 2", "Store 3"]
products = ["Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"]

# Xij = 1 if product j is purchased at store i, else = 0;
X = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("X", [(i, j) for i in stores for j in products], cat="Binary")
# Si = 1 if store i is available, else = 0.
S = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("S", stores, cat="Binary")

# Define the objective function
C = {
    ("Store 1", "Product 1"): 1,
    ("Store 1", "Product 2"): 3,
    ("Store 1", "Product 3"): 4,
    ("Store 2", "Product 1"): 3,
    ("Store 2", "Product 2"): 1,
    ("Store 2", "Product 3"): 3,
    ("Store 3", "Product 1"): 2,
    ("Store 3", "Product 2"): 3,
    ("Store 3", "Product 3"): 1,
}

# Minimize Σij CijXij, where Cij is the cost of purchasing product j from store i
problem += pulp.lpSum([C[(i, j)] * X[(i, j)] for i in stores for j in products])

# Subject to constraints
for j in products:
# Σi Xij = 1 for all products j (each product is purchased at some store)
    problem += pulp.lpSum([X[(i, j)] for i in stores]) == 1
    for i in stores:
# Xij <= Si for all i,j (can only purchase at store i if store i is available)
        problem += pulp.lpSum(X[(i, j)]) <= S[i]

# Subject to constraint Σi Si <= n (at most n stores available)
problem += pulp.lpSum([S[i] for i in stores]) <= 2

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

# Print the results
for v in problem.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print("Total Cost =", pulp.value(problem.objective))
```

The output:

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                4.00000000

Enumerated nodes:               0

Total iterations:               0

Time (CPU seconds):             0.00

Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all

Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

S_Store_1 = 0.0

S_Store_2 = 1.0

S_Store_3 = 1.0

X_('Store_1',_'Product_1') = 0.0

X_('Store_1',_'Product_2') = 0.0

X_('Store_1',_'Product_3') = 0.0

X_('Store_2',_'Product_1') = 0.0

X_('Store_2',_'Product_2') = 1.0

X_('Store_2',_'Product_3') = 0.0

X_('Store_3',_'Product_1') = 1.0

X_('Store_3',_'Product_2') = 0.0

X_('Store_3',_'Product_3') = 1.0

Total Cost = 4.0